# How to assign (add) value to a undefined item in a json object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I have a external json file and I parse it in to local object,
Currently I know I can't push value into a object so I want to assign a value to them here is my code:

```
//I parse my JSON into object and name it data
var data = {
  ...
}
// I use this object as a database so I don't list it all out
var name = "title";
var content = "hello guys";
data[name] = content;
// I wish after this script the object will have one more item like
// {
//  ...
//  "title": "hello guys",
//  ...
//}
```

But the vscode's console show the following error when I run the script

```
TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined
```

If you can assign value to undefined object how can you add item in to object.

But if there is any way that can let me assign value to undefined item, I'll be very happy

#### Here is the full code if you need

```
var jsonfile = require('jsonfile')

var file = './test.json'
var data = jsonfile.readFileSync(file); //I'm very sure data isn't undefined
//console.log(data);
var name="title";
var content="hello guys";
data.post[name] = content;

jsonfile.writeFileSync(file, tmd, {spaces: 4});
```

Comment: You parse a string as JSON, but if you already have it as json just import it and use it as it is.

Comment: in your screenshot you are doing `data.post[name] = content` in the question you have done `data[name] = content` please make the code snippets consistent with what you want to do.

Comment: @Dij that does not matter the location i want to post in under `post` but in here the question I made it simpler so I move the location to the toppest location

Comment: as I said. you dont have to PARSE! require will do it for you ( require(·./yourjsonfile.json·) )

Comment: @taha I didn't PARSE it if I did where? I'm working on nodejs and usually we use readfile function

Answer (score 1):

currently `data = undefined` and you are trying to access a key in `undefined` that is why you are getting an error, you need to assign an empty object to data if it is undefined. you can do something like this:

```
var data = data || {};
var name = "title";
var content = "hello guys";
data[name] = content;
```

Comment: Oops sorry I didn't say clear I already have a object and assign as variable data then I want to add a item but object can't use push so I think I use assigning value to add a new item but fail

Comment: if data is already an object then you should not get that error. The error clearly says you are trying to set property 'title' of undefined, which means data is undefined. Nevertheless   `var data = data || {}` will initialize data with {} if it is undefined.

Comment: Yeap `data.title` is undefined usually if it's a array we'll use push to create item but here is object and I want to create a new item called title with value content the error is right `data.title` is undefined that's b/c I want to create it

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'title' of undefined` means you are setting a property named title of something undefined. This means data is undefined.

Comment: Ok I get it when I set the value to null it works and when I change back to variable `content` it still work but now I have no idea where went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Probably data has no key named 'post'.
Try this:

```
data.post = data.post || {};
data.post[name] = content;
```

EDIT:
I know this is old, but maybe it will help someone.
Here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options states that readFileSync returns string not data structure.

Comment: If you don't mind here is a snapshot of the console and code  https://1drv.ms/i/s!AifrtKYSrTy64jeiAn1Rd_YMSQom